# Rails twitter bootstrap icons don't show up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using `gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails'` in a Rails app.

It was working fine until this morning.  I removed another gem and did a `bundle install`.

Now my Bootstrap icons don't show up.  I'm using the native Bootstrap icons.  Here is an example display:

```
<i class="icon-search"></i>
```

Also, the Rails app wouldn't run until I remove this line from application.css

```
 *= require bootstrap
```

I tried adding this line:

```
 *= require twitter-bootstrap-static/sprites
```

But, that didn't work.

I have these statements in the `bootstrap_and_overrides.css.scss`

```
@import "bootstrap";
@import "bootstrap-responsive";
```

This is in my external libraries:

[image]

Thanks for the help!

Comment: any errors in Chrome Dev Tools or Firebug?

Comment: Yes `GET http://ame.ndeavor2.dev/assets/glyphicons-halflings.png 404 (Not Found) `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try copying `glyphicons-halflings.png` to `RAILS_ROOT/app/assets/images`. Do you still get the 404 - page not found error?

Comment: Thanks - That worked.  But, I don't understand why I had to add a copy to that location.

Answer (score 0):

i had same problem too. 
you need to move `glyphicons-halflins.png` and `glyphicons-halflings-white.png` under `app/public/fonts/` folder or `app/public/images` folder